# $G$ is an abelian group and for each $g \in G$ not equal to $e$, $g^2$ not equal to $e$. Prove if $a,b \in G$ and $a^2 =b^2$, then $a=b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I understand that $G$ being Abelian means $ab=ba$. I've tried using the inverses starting with $a^2=b^2$ to prove that $a=b$, but I also get stuck. Any help would be much appreciated. I've looked at examples of $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ which didn't help much.

Comment: Well, suppose $g^2\neq g$. Then, if we let $e=g^2$, then the condition is violated for $e$ and $g$. So for all $g\in G$, we have that $g^2=g$, i.e., that each element is idempotent. So, if $a^2=b^2$, then $a^2=a=b=b^2$.

Comment: Hint:  multiply both sides by $\left(b^{-1}\right)^2$.

Comment: By hypothesis you know that if $g^2=e$, then $g=e$. Thus, if $a^2=b^2$ then as $G$ is an abelian group $a^{2}(b^{-1})^2=(ab^{-1})^2=e$ and yo can use the hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

$a^2=b^2$

So

$(ab^{-1})^2=e$

But this means

$ab^{-1}=e$

that implies

$a=b$

Answer (score 0):

If $a^2=b^2$, then, multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ and given $G$ is Abelian, we have $ab^{-1}=a^{-1}b$.

But then $(ab^{-1})^2=ab^{-1}a^{-1}b=e$, so $ab^{-1}=e$ by the hypothesis that $g^2\ne e$ unless $g=e$,

so $a=b$.